# jQuery find not working correctly when iterating over TD

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery script that allows the user to step from input element to input element in a table using the cursor keys. I specify a style class 'tableInput' on input elements that should get the focus.
That works fine if the next TD has has an input element.

I am not a jQuery expert so I just tried to iterate over the TDs until I find a input element with the style class:

```
 jQuery(':input.tableInput').live("keyup",function(e){
var charPos = e.target.selectionStart;
var endPos = e.target.selectionEnd;
var strLength = e.target.value.length;
var prevPos = $(this).data('prevPos');
if(e.which==39){
    if(charPos==strLength && (prevPos ==null || prevPos == charPos)){
        var nextTd = $(this).closest('td').next();
        console.log("Next td",nextTd);
        var count = 0;
        while(nextTd){
            var comp = $(nextTd).find(':input.tableInput');
            console.log("Comp ",comp);
  // Returns the previous input component of the original td when no        //input can be found
            if(comp){
                comp.focus();
                break;
            }
            nextTd = $(nextTd).next();
            console.log("Next td",nextTd);

        }
        $(this).data('prevPos',null);
    }else{
        $(this).data('prevPos',charPos);
    }
}
```

The problem is that $(nextTd).find(':input.tableInput') returns the original input component when the 'nextTd' component doesn't have an input element. Why is that? Is there a better way of doing this?

So lets say I have a table with 4 columns. Column 1 and 3 contain an input element with the style class tableInput.
When I click on the right key on the input in col1 the following happens:

var nextTd = $(this).closest('td').next() returns col2.
$(nextTd).find('input:tableInput') return input1 instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it just show that I should stick to the backend ;-)

find() will always return a jQuery object so the check
if(comp) is wrong when I do if(comp.get(0)) it seems to work.